# Unexpected blank line after rasterizing sf object

Tags: r, geospatial, rasterizing

After rasterizing the sf object and plotting it, I see unexpected blank lines both horizontally and vertically.

```r
tmp_r <- fasterize(tmp_buf, afr_r, field = "rwi", fun = "first") |> 
    terra::rast()
```

`tmp_buf` originally looks like this: [tmp_buf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aGcB.png)

Image after rasterizing:
[tmp_r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnGhp.png)

I tried almost every rasterizing method, all resulting in the same unexpected blank lines.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible. Have a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Which library exports `fasterize()`?

Comment: That does not look unexpected but it is hard to be sure without a *minimal self-contained, reproducible example*. Also, it seems that you first vectorize raster data to polygons, and then rasterize the polygons again. Why?